# Extract attachments from .msg files saved in a folder using excel vba - subdirectories

Tags: excel, vba, subdirectory, msg

Was able to put together something to go through the main folder and pick up msg files and extract attachments
I want the code to be able to loop through subfolders also
How would I go about it? I've seen a few threads on the topic but I'm having difficulty translating it to what I've got

'''

```
Dim outApp As Object
Dim outEmail As Object
Dim outAttachment As Object
Dim msgfiles As String, sourceFolder As String, saveInFolder As String
Dim fileName As String

msgfiles = "C:\test\*.msg"       'CHANGE - folder location and filespec of .msg files
saveInFolder = "C:\test 2"         'CHANGE - folder where extracted attachments are saved

If Right(saveInFolder, 1) <> "\" Then saveInFolder = saveInFolder & "\"
sourceFolder = Left(msgfiles, InStrRev(msgfiles, "\"))

On Error Resume Next
Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If outApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Outlook is not open"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0

fileName = dir(msgfiles)
While fileName <> vbNullString

    'Open .msg file in Outlook 2003
    'Set outEmail = outApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(sourceFolder & fileName)

    'Open .msg file in Outlook 2007+
    Set outEmail = outApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(sourceFolder & fileName)

    For Each outAttachment In outEmail.Attachments
        outAttachment.SaveAsFile saveInFolder & outAttachment.fileName
    Next

    fileName = dir

Wend
```

'''

EDIT

Including code below after first suggestion

```
Sub LoopThrough(parentFolder As String)
Dim fso As Object
    ' Create a File System object to loop through folders
    If fso Is Nothing Then
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    End If

    ' Get the specified folder
    Dim folder As Object
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(parentFolder)

    ' Call my code on it
    MyCode msgfiles.Path

    ' Get all sub folders
    Dim subFolder As Object
    On Error Resume Next                    ' We might have permission issues so lets carry on if we get a folder we cannot access
    For Each subFolder In folder.subfolders
        On Error GoTo 0                     ' If we cant access the folder, reset error
        If Not subFolder Is Nothing Then    ' Folder will be null/nothing if we had an error so ignore it if it is
            LoopThrough subFolder.Path
        End If
        On Error Resume Next                ' When going back over the loop  we can still get an error
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub MyCode(folder As String)
    Debug.Print folder
    msgfiles = folder & "\*.msg"
    ' Your code Here

Dim outApp As Object
Dim outEmail As Object
Dim outAttachment As Object
Dim msgfiles As String, sourceFolder As String, saveInFolder As String
Dim fileName As String

msgfiles = "C:\test\*.msg"       'CHANGE - folder location and filespec of .msg files
saveInFolder = "C:\test 2"         'CHANGE - folder where extracted attachments are saved

If Right(saveInFolder, 1) <> "\" Then saveInFolder = saveInFolder & "\"
sourceFolder = Left(msgfiles, InStrRev(msgfiles, "\"))

On Error Resume Next
Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If outApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Outlook is not open"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0

fileName = Dir(msgfiles)
While fileName <> vbNullString

    'Open .msg file in Outlook 2003
    'Set outEmail = outApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(sourceFolder & fileName)

    'Open .msg file in Outlook 2007+
    Set outEmail = outApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(sourceFolder & fileName)

    For Each outAttachment In outEmail.Attachments
        outAttachment.SaveAsFile saveInFolder & outAttachment.fileName
    Next

    fileName = Dir

Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This loops through a directory and it's sub-directories. It will call `MyCode` and pass in the folder's full path. You will need to modify `MyCode` to do what you want.

```
Sub LoopThrough(parentFolder As String)
Dim fso As Object
    ' Create a File System object to loop through folders
    If fso Is Nothing Then
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    End If

    ' Get the specified folder
    Dim folder As Object
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(parentFolder)

    ' Call my code on it
    MyCode msgfiles.Path

    ' Get all sub folders
    Dim subFolder As Object
    On Error Resume Next                    ' We might have permission issues so lets carry on if we get a folder we cannot access
    For Each subFolder In folder.subfolders
        On Error GoTo 0                     ' If we cant access the folder, reset error
        If Not subFolder Is Nothing Then    ' Folder will be null/nothing if we had an error so ignore it if it is
            LoopThrough subFolder.Path
        End If
        On Error Resume Next                ' When going back over the loop  we can still get an error
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub MyCode(folder As String)
    Dim outApp As Object
    Dim outEmail As Object
    Dim outAttachment As Object
    Dim msgfiles As String, sourceFolder As String, saveInFolder As String
    Dim fileName As String

    Debug.Print folder
    msgfiles = folder & "\*.msg"
    ' Your code Here


    ''msgfiles = "C:\test\*.msg"       'CHANGE - folder location and filespec of .msg files
    saveInFolder = "C:\test 2"         'CHANGE - folder where extracted attachments are saved

    If Right(saveInFolder, 1) <> "\" Then saveInFolder = saveInFolder & "\"
    sourceFolder = Left(msgfiles, InStrRev(msgfiles, "\"))

    On Error Resume Next
    Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If outApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Outlook is not open"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    fileName = Dir(msgfiles)
    While fileName <> vbNullString

        'Open .msg file in Outlook 2003
        'Set outEmail = outApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(sourceFolder & fileName)

        'Open .msg file in Outlook 2007+
        Set outEmail = outApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(sourceFolder & fileName)

        For Each outAttachment In outEmail.Attachments
            outAttachment.SaveAsFile saveInFolder & outAttachment.fileName
        Next

        fileName = Dir

    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this and it still only does it for the top folder. Perhaps I'm doing it wrong. Would it be possible for you to provide more detail?

Comment: Please would you be able to edit your question and add the code you're using now?

Comment: Updated as requested

Comment: @Scarborough12345 Please find this should now be updated